Maximum of coefficients of a quadratic equation
Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ ($a\ne 0$) be a quadratic function. Given a specific $n\in\mathbb N_+$, $f(x)$ satisfies that for all $x\in[-n,n]$, $|f(x)|\leq n$. Find the maximum of $|a|+|b|+|c|$.
My initial guess is $\frac{2}{n}+n$ given the function $f(x)=\frac{2}{n}x^2-n$ satisfies the constraints above.
However, my best estimation is that $|a|+|b|+|c|\leq \frac{2}{n}x^2+n+1$ holds.
To justify this, consider the values of $f(x)$ where $x=n,-n$ and $0$. It will lead to a linear equation of $a, b, c$, which simplifies to
$$
a=\frac{1}{2n^2}(f(n)+f(-n)-2f(0)), \quad b=\frac{1}{2n}(f(n)-f(-n)), \quad c=f(0). 
$$
However, using such estimation can only derive that
$$|a|+|b|+|c|=\left|\frac{1}{2n^2}(f(n)+f(-n)-2f(0))\right|+\left|\frac{1}{2n}(f(n)-f(-n))\right|+\left|f(0)\right|.$$
Using $|f(x)|\leq n$ and triangle inequality we can get
$$|a|+|b|+|c|=\left(\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\left(\left|f(n)\right|+\left|f(-n)\right|\right)+\left(\frac{2}{2n^2}+1\right)\left|f(0)\right|\leq n+\frac{2}{n}+1.$$
This is a constant away from the initial guess. Is there a better way of estimation? Or is it possible to construct a certain function whose sum of the absolute value of its coefficients is $n+\frac{2}{n}+1$? Any form of help would be appreciated.

$n-x-\frac{1}{n}x^2$ doesn't go outside of the bounds for $x \in {-n,0,n }$, but does for other $x \in [-n,n]$. So that is nearly the strongest bound you can prove for the constraints you've identified, but there are additional constraints that you haven't made use of yet.

Remark 1. I let $f(-b/(2a)) = -n$ and $f(n) = n$ to maximize $a + b - c$ which gives the $a, b, c$ in Fact 1.
Remark 2. The $a, b, c$ in Fact 1 satisfies $- \frac{b}{2a} = - \frac{n-1}{n+1} \in [-n, n]$ if $n\ge 1$. When $c < 0$, the two values $f(n), f(-\frac{n-1}{n+1})$ are enough to imply the upper bound $a + b - c \le n + \frac{4n}{n^2 + 2n - 1}$.
$\phantom{2}$

Fact 1. Let $f(x) := ax^2 + bx + c$ ($a \ne 0$) be a quadratic function. Given $n \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 1}$, $f(x)$ satisfies $|f(x)| \le n$ for all $x\in [-n, n]$. Then the maximum of $|a| + |b| + |c|$ is given by
$n + \frac{4n}{n^2 + 2n - 1}$, when (e.g.)
$$a = \frac{2n(n + 1)^2}{(n^2 + 2n - 1)^2}, 
\quad b = \frac{4n(n^2 - 1)}{(n^2 + 2n - 1)^2}, \quad c = - \frac{n(n^4 + 4n^3 - 1)}{(n^2 + 2n - 1)^2}.$$
Fact 2. Let $f(x) := ax^2 + bx + c$ ($a \ne 0$) be a quadratic function. Given $n \in (0, 1)$, $f(x)$ satisfies $|f(x)| \le n$ for all $x\in [-n, n]$. Then the maximum of $|a| + |b| + |c|$ is given by $\frac{2}{n} + n$ when e.g.
$f(x) = \frac{2}n x^2 - n$.
$\phantom{2}$
Proof of Fact 1.
WLOG, assume that $a > 0$ and $b \ge 0$. We split into two cases.
Case 1. $c \ge 0$
We have
$|a| + |b| + |c| = a + b + c \le an^2 + bn + c = f(n) \le n < n + \frac{4n}{n^2 + 2n - 1}$.
Case 2. $c < 0$
Since $-\frac{n-1}{n+1} \in [-n, n]$, we have
$ - f(-\frac{n-1}{n+1}) \le n$. We have
\begin{align*}
 |a| + |b| + |c| &= a + b - c\\
 &=
 \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2+2n-1}\cdot \left[- f\left(-\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)\right]
 + \frac{2}{n^2+2n-1}\cdot f(n)\\
 &\le \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2+2n-1}\cdot n
 + \frac{2}{n^2+2n-1}\cdot n\\
 &= n + \frac{4n}{n^2 + 2n - 1}.
\end{align*}
We are done.
$\phantom{2}$
Proof of Fact 2.
WLOG, assume that $a > 0$ and $b \ge 0$.
We split into two cases.
Case 1. $c \ge 0$
Since $f(n) = an^2 + bn + c \le n$, we have
$a + b/n + c/n^2 \le 1/n$. Thus, we have
$$|a| + |b| + |c| = a + b + c \le a + b/n + c/n^2 \le \frac{1}{n} < \frac{2}{n} + n.$$
Case 2. $c < 0$
We have
\begin{align*}
 |a| + |b| + |c| &= a + b - c\\
 &= \frac{n+1}{2n^2}\cdot f(n) + \frac{1-n}{2n^2}\cdot f(-n) + \frac{n^2+1}{n^2}\cdot [-f(0)]\\
 &\le \frac{n+1}{2n^2}\cdot n + \frac{1-n}{2n^2}\cdot n + \frac{n^2+1}{n^2}\cdot n\\
 &= \frac{2}{n} + n.
\end{align*}
We are done.

Amusingly, this can be solved without calculus.
First, we can assume wlog $a,b>0$ and $c<0$* so $|a|+|b|+|c|=a+b-c$. Clearly the maximum over the range is then at $x=n$. If $n$ isn't obtained anywhere in the range, $a$ could be increased, so
$$an^2+bn+c=n \tag{❤️}$$
If $-n$ isn't obtained anywhere, $c$ can be decreased, so $-n$ is obtained. This could either be an internal minimum or a boundary solution at $x=-n$, giving us two cases:
In the boundary case, knowing $f(-n)=-n$ and $f(n)=n$ fixes $a$ and $b$, so we want to find the quadratic satisfying this that minimises $c$. Expanded around $x=-n$, $f(x)=\alpha(x+n)^2+\beta(x+n)-n$. Expanding out
$$\alpha(x+n)^2+\beta(x+n)-n=ax^2+bx+c$$
we find $a=\alpha$, $b=\beta+2n\alpha$ and $c= n^2\alpha + n\beta-n$, so $a+b-c$ is decreasing in $\beta$ and decreasing $\beta$ helps rather than hinders us satisfying $❤️$, so we want $\beta$ to be as low as possible, which means $\beta=0$, as if $\beta<0$, $x=-n$ wouldn't be the minimum. This tells us that the minimum is at $-n$, so will actually be covered by our interior solution case.
Case 2: The minimum is interior and $\le 0$ so $f(x)=\alpha(x+\mu)^2-c$ for some $\mu \in [0,n]$.
$$\alpha(x+\mu)^2-n=ax^2+bx+c$$
tells us that $a=\alpha$, $b=2\alpha\mu$ and $c=\alpha \mu^2-n$. By $❤️$ we have $\alpha(n+\mu)^2-n=n$ so $a=\alpha=\frac{2n}{(n+\mu)^2}$. Substituting this gives
$$a+b-c=\frac{2n}{(n+\mu)^2}+\frac{4n\mu}{(n+\mu)^2}-\frac{2n\mu^2}{(n+\mu)^2}+n$$
The denominator has degree $2$, so we can minimise wrt $\mu$ without calculus, and we find $\mu=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ if $n \ge 1$ and $\mu=0$ otherwise (as $\mu \ge 0$). We can then substitute $\mu$ to find
$$\alpha=\frac{2n(n+1)^2}{(n-1)^4}$$
which in turn can be substituted into
$$a+b-c=\alpha (1+2\mu-\mu^2)+n$$
to give something quite messy, which is our final answer, assuming my calculations are thus far correct. (Wolfram Alpha isn't loading for me and I don't want to do it by hand)
Sorry this is a bit of a mess, I'll try to come back and neaten it.
*We can make $a>0$ by flipping vertically, $b>0$ by flipping horizontally and if $a$ and $c$ have the same sign you can always switch $c$'s sign.

Proceeding from your calculation, $a+b-c = \frac{n \left(n^2+2 n+3\right)}{n^2+2 n-1} = n+\frac{4 n}{n^2+2 n-1}$, which can be obtained when $a=\frac{2n(n+1)^2}{(n-1)^4}, b=\frac{4n(n+1)}{(n-1)^3},c=\frac{2n}{(n-1)^2}-n$. And this fits the constraints above. I really appreciate your help!

Minor issue: it seems that your alterations towards $a, c$ might derive infinite alterations for changing $f(n)$ to $n$ might also affect $c$, so it seemed a little ambiguous. A better way might be rewriting $f$ into $a(x-x_0)^2+e$.

"we can assume wlog $a,b>0$ and $c<0$": ok for $a,b>0$, but why $c<0$?

@AnneBauval if $a$ and $c$ have the same sign you can always switch $c$'s sign. I guess that should be in the answer.

A more obvious interpretation is that if $c>0$ then $|a|+|b|+|c|=f(1)\leqslant n$ which is smaller than $n+\frac{4n}{n^2+2n-1}$.

(UPDATE: The solution given by user @River Li (Fact 1), appears to check out, so treat the following elaborations as having somewhere some mistake.)
Let's see if the following make sense.
I will use the sign function
$$s(z) \equiv \begin{cases} -1 & z<0 \\ 0 & z=0 \\ 1 & z>0 \end{cases}$$
It would appear that we can formulate the problem as
$$\max_{(|a|,|b|,|c|)} V \equiv |a|+|b|+|c|$$
$$s.t.\quad  a \neq 0,\quad  |b|\geq 0, \quad |c|\geq 0,$$
$$\quad f=\Big|s(a)|a|x^2 + s(b)|b|x + s(c)|c|\Big| \leq n, \quad x\in [-n, n]. $$
The Lagrangean is, with non-negative KKT multipliers,
$$\Lambda = |a|+|b|+|c| + \lambda\cdot \left(n-\Big|s(a)|a|x^2 + s(b)|b|x + s(c)|c|\Big|\right) +\mu_b|b| +\mu_c|c|.$$
Then, at the optimum, if it exists and denoted by a star ($*$)
$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial |a|} = 0 \implies 1 = \lambda^*\cdot s(f^*)\cdot s(a^*)\cdot (x^*)^2  \tag{1} $$
$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial |b|} = 0 \implies 1+\mu_b = \lambda^*\cdot s(f^*)\cdot s(b^*)\cdot x^*   \tag{2} $$
$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial |c|} = 0 \implies 1+\mu_c = \lambda^*\cdot s(f^*)\cdot s(c^*).   \tag{3} $$
From $(1)$ we learn : $\lambda^* > 0$ so the constraint is binding and at the maximum we will have
$$ |f^*|=n \tag{4}$$
Also, we learn that the sign of $a^*$ will be the same as the sign of $f^*$
$$\implies s(f^*)\cdot s(a^*) =1 \tag{5}$$
...which also implies that $f^* \neq 0$ (which is good because the derivative of its absolute value does not exist at $f=0$).
We also learn that the maximum won't happen at $x=0$.
From $(2)$ we learn that
$$s(b^*)\neq 0 \implies b^* \neq 0 \implies \mu_b =0 \tag {6}$$
From $(3)$ we learn
$$s(c^*)\neq 0 \implies c^* \neq 0 \implies \mu_c =0 \tag {7}$$
and that
$$s(f^*) = s(c^*)\implies  s(f^*) \cdot  s(c^*)=1. \tag{8}$$
Collecting results and their consequences, at the optimum the conditions will be
$$1 = \lambda^*\cdot (x^*)^2  \tag{1a} $$
$$1 = \lambda^*\cdot s(f^*)\cdot s(b^*)\cdot x^*   \tag{2a} $$
$$1 = \lambda^*.   \tag{3a} $$
which in turn imply
$$|x^*| =1 \tag{9}$$
$$s(f^*)\cdot s(b^*)\cdot x^* = 1 \tag{10}.$$
CASE $1$:  $x^*=1$.
Then from $(10)$ we have $s(f^*)= s(b^*)$ so all three $a,b,c$ will have the same sign, say $s^*$.
Then, since, from $(4)$,
$$|f^*| = n \implies \Big | s^* |a_1^*| + s^* |b_1^*| + s^* |c_1^*| \Big| = n \implies |a_1^*| +  |b_1^*| +  |c_1^*| = n = V^*_1\tag {11}$$
This is one possible solution.
CASE $2$:  $x^*=-1$.
Here, again due to $(10)$, the sign of $b$ will be the opposite of the sign of $f, a,c$, but also $x=-1$ so we have
$$|f^*| = n \implies \Big | s^* |a_2^*| - s^* |b_2^*|\cdot (-1) + s^* |c_2^*| \Big| = n $$
which gives us exactly the same condition as in case 1. So it appears we have arrived at the possibility that

The maximum of $|a| + |b| + |c|$ is equal to $n$ and
it will happen at $|x|=1$.

